# The type "Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement" is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, uwp, .net-native

I have an UWP app that i'm trying to build. 
It all works fine in debug mode, but when i switch to release and then try to build, it shows the error

> error CS0012: The type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement' is defined
>   in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to
>   assembly 'Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null, ContentType=WindowsRuntime'.

I've narrowd it down to the project property called "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" being the source of the problem. Atleast the project can build when i uncheck that property. 
I would however prefer to have the option enabled. 
I've added references to the Windows Desktop and Windows Mobile extensions.

Any idea of what i need to do to fix this?

Comment: I work on the .NET Native Runtime and Compiler team. I don't know what's happening but would love to take a look. A reasonable set of steps for getting us a repro are outlined here: https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/ilcRepro.md

Comment: I've followed the steps, outlined on the page you referenced.

Comment: Thanks. I see your mail and we'll take a look in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting Matt, he and his colleagues discovered that it was an error in .NET Native. So i just have to wait for the next update to .NET Native.

EDIT: 
After the latest update to Visual Studio 2015 (update 3), I can now successfully build the app in release mode with .NET native toolchain! Huzzah!

Answer (score 0):

I've had far too many problems with developing for Windows Universal.
I've had problems similar to this. Re-install your Windows 10 SDK, This solved it for me!

Comment: I already tried this, but thanks for the suggestion :) 
But as it turns out, the error is not on my machine or code, but in .NET Native.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question. Do you use XmlSerializer to serialize a type which references winmd type? In your case the winmd type seems to be 'Windows.UI.Xaml.FrameworkElement'? If so, please have a look at my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37865469/3186857) for that question. It seems that .Net Native tools have problem with generating XmlSerializer for types referencing winmd types.