# Cannot compile Release build of UWP - Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2017, uwp-xaml, syncfusion

I have finished a small Windows 10 app in C# and XAML and now I want to do a "Release" build of the app so that I can create app package.

The problem is: VS 2017 cannot create a release build of the app.

Please see the error message which VS give out after trying to release-build for around 20 mins.
[image]

I'm using Syncfusion PDF Viewer control in the app & hence have added reference to "Syncfusion Controls for UWP XAML".

I have tried un-checking the "Compile with .NET Native tool chain" in properties page. It works and I can do a release-build, BUT the Windows App Cert Kit "fails" my app.

Another information which I would like to add is: even if I do a File -> New UWP Project and try to do a release build of that - it still does not work.

I've also read the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680536/cant-build-uwp-in-release-mode), but it's does not seem relevant to my project. e.g., I am not referencing a winmd type.

What could be wrong?

Comment: Did you add a reference to both Syncfusion.SfPdfViewer.UWP and 
Syncfusion.Pdf.UWP?

Comment: Have you tried updating and repairing Visual Studio?

Comment: @KenTucker Yes, I added both, but same error. But now "Internal Compiler Error" does not occur.

The error is:
Error  ILT0005: 'C:Users\<USERNAME>\.nuget\packages\microsoft.net.native.compiler\1.7.0\tools\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe 
@"C:\Users\<USERNAME>\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\InspDemoApp\InspDemoApp\obj\x86\Release\ilc\intermediate\MDIL\InspDemoApp.rsp"' returned exit code 1 InspDemoApp

Comment: Another thing is, I don't remember what I did, I only added reference to those 2 files - but now my "obj" and "bin" folder's combined size is 4.61GB!!!

Comment: Using the hammer approach, I deleted both the "obj" and "bin" folders (because the size didn't look right and anyways this is a demo project and I have backup)

Comment: What could be the reason for "-1" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the hammer approach, I deleted both the "obj" and "bin" folders (because the size didn't look right and anyways this is a demo project and I have backup)

After deleting, I set to release and build - and it worked!

Good thing, but it took 40 mins. Then after the first release-build, I changed some xaml and added some code (added button which show "Hello" dialog) and tried to build again. It failed.

Then I deleted bin and obj folders and then it worked again. But combined size of both folders is now 3.92 GB.

So everytime I need to do a release-build, I have to delete bin & obj folders and wait for appx 35~45 mins.

I will now repair VS 2017 as @Marian suggested and will let you know what happens. 
I do not know if this is an answer or it's rather a work-around.

Comment: There's no definite solution other than the workaround mentioned. Repairing VS 2017 did not solve this.

Answer (score 0):

We are unable to reproduce the mentioned compilation error issue while running the sample in Visual Studio 2017 with Release mode. We have attached the sample for your reference. Please find the sample from below link.

http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/189981/ze/Sample687065144.zip

Kindly provide us the following details to reproduce the issue at our end: 
•   Simple sample along with the input document.
•   Operation System:
•   .Net Framework:
•   Syncfusion Essential Studio Version:
•   RAM:
•   System Culture Information:

The above details will be helpful for us to assist you better on this.

Regards,
Priyanga.E

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is "Syncfusion controls". Details about this [here](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/129923/how-to-add-syncfusion-extension-for-build-uwp-app-in-release-mode)
You need to remove the extension ""Syncfusion Controls for UWP Xaml" and add path to syncfusion libraries(which you use) .